# Astropy.table Unique() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, astropy

I'm having some problems with unique function after updating astropy

code:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np
table = Table(data=[[1,2,3,2,3,3],[2,3,4,5,4,6],[3,4,5,6,7,8]],
    names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
    dtype=[np.int32, np.int32, np.int32])

unique(table, keys='col1')
```

error in jupyter notebook

```
NameError: name 'unique' is not defined
```

error in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'unique' is not defined
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to import it from `astropy.table`:

```
from astropy.table import unique
```

The [example in the documentation](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.unique.html) (that you use in your question) is incorrect.

The signature of the function in that same documentation page makes it clear where it comes from:

> `astropy.table.unique(input_table, keys=None, silent=False, keep='first')`